# When to use comma with then

Tags: commas

I learned English long time ago. The native speaker teacher told me that we always use comma after the word `then`. However, one proofreader told me that I must not write a comma after `then`. I am really confuse. Could some one please explain to me when it is correct to use comma with `then`?

For example,

> Then, the next step is estimating the model parameters.
>
> Set `x` as a first point, then, find the point `y` given `x`.

Comment: Could you add a few examples of either case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some circumstances that a comma should be used after ***then***:

> "It is good, **then**, that you wish to learn more."

But your examples aren't such circumstances. When using *then* to indicate a sequence of events, either in reporting events or giving instructions, it should not normally have a comma (though there are always exceptions, like there being a parenthetical clause immediately after it). When used in a similar sense to *therefore*, it may or may not want a comma after it - to the same standards as if you were using the word *therefore*.

Answer (score 0):

Then can be used as an adverb, conjunction, noun, and an adjective. There is no definitive answer to your question because

- as it frequently introduces a dependent phrase, however, a comma would be placed at the end of the independent phrase or clause which precedes it.
- The use of a comma is more art than science. What’s ‘correct’ varies depending on the sense and composition of a sentence.
  In general, you should probably place a comma at every point where you would pause if you were reading the words you’re writing out loud.
  It’s virtually mandatory to use them to separate words or phrases in a list (They were red, white, smooth in texture, and triangular in shape). They’re also very helpful in setting-off clauses that:
- describe separate actions (went to the office; left for the airport)
- communicate descriptive information that’s important but without which the rest of the sentence would still make sense (around noon).
  Some people use commas a lot more than others. As a ‘rule of thumb’: if your sentence needs too many commas, it needs to be re-written and you probably have clauses in it that should be sentences on their own.
  Conjunctive adverbs are followed by a comma.
  Examples:
- I ate, then I started home.( adverb )
- Read the instructions well , then start answering. (conjunction )